# Laravel 8 rest api gives 404 error with nuxt frontend

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, single-page-application

I am working on Laravel 8 restful API and Nuxt as a frontend.
I have deployed rest API on a subdomain and it's working with the postman.

I have created a build for the frontend and test it on local, it's working fine but the issue which I am getting is that when I deployed the frontend on the live server then every API call gives 404 error.

[image: Network tab screenshot]

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k277n.png)

Can any volunteer help me please on it?

Comment: can you show the response?

Comment: sure. please check i have attached it above

Comment: Are you attempting to access an address in your `prod` environment which is only accessible to your `local` environment?

Comment: thanks. solved!
I have just set the env checked for prod on the proxy in axios (nuxt.config.js) and it works.

Comment: WHat do you mean by env checked for prod??